# How can we have totally new moderation leadership and rules?

Tags: feature-request, moderation, off-topic

I've been a WP pro for 10 years. I have never heard - even one time - a person verbally say something good about this site. It is pretty much universally reviled as being the domain of downvote cops and people who spend all day typing the phrase "off topic".

Seams traffic has TANKED, or at least participation has. Is there an executive at SE who cares about that? What's that person's name?

So my question... if we wanted to do it... what would it take to totally overthrow the entire moderation leadership? Maybe a vote to blank out the reputations of everyone?

Comment: I'd love to hear the excuses for the downvotes please. I'm only asking how it can be done. Seams like a reasonable question for meta.

Comment: What do you mean by blank out the reputation? If you mean resetting everyone's reputation point to 1, why would anyone agree with that?

Comment: I think the vast majority of people here would welcome that, if it meant new leadership. Especially if we count the thousands of users who have given up the site in disgust!

Comment: Up to 10 new users per hour asking one sentence questions about some premium plugins. Complaining is fine, but what else then maybe reseting reputation is your exact plan to fix things?

Comment: Don't forget, most of the people commenting here are community members with the same powers and priviledges you have, and those with the diamonds had to justify and win votes in an election, nobody here is paid and it's rare we see a Stack Exchange employee outside of election announcements and when serious misconduct occurs (none come to mind). There's no official WPSE stance, we're our own individuals. Being a moderator doesn't give me many more powers than a high reputation user either, most moderation on the site doesn't involve moderators

Answer (score 9):

I think you are misunderstanding our model: moderators are not leaders. They are exception handlers and bound to the scope set by the community.

If you think one ore more moderators have overstepped, contact the community managers. That's the **Contact** link in the footer of every page.

In any case, be specific. General statements about the community without even a single example are usually no a good way to start a constructive conversation.

Be assured that we have discussions about our site's current state and scope. But as moderators, we can't redefine that scope, that's up to the community as a whole.

Feel free to make constructive suggestion for improvements. Throwing everything away and starting from scratch, however that even could be done, will very likely not be accepted by the community.

Comment: I thought I was making a constructive suggestion for improvement: Permanent changes in the moderation system. Get rid of the PEOPLE doing it today and modify it. That's my suggestion. I don't expect anyone here on this meta to agree with me! You have it locked up, and no one uses this board except to complain on their way out the door to Quora, or Woo's commercial board.

Comment: You are the guy who is stepping into a room full of people and tells everyone to leave? Maybe it's easier and more polite not to enter that room in the first place?

Comment: No, I'm definitely asking everyone with a diamond here to please leave! It's not about you personally. It's about how this site has gone down hill. No one is answering questions anymore, and there is a tremendous amount of bickering and rules lawyering. So yeah, I'm definitely trying to show you guys the door. Stay tuned.

Comment: We are elected by the community. You, an outsider, are essentially asking to undo decisions made by the community. If you don't get how rude and pointless that is, then maybe you are wrong here?

Comment: I'm not an outsider. I'm a trac CC and a contributor here for over 10 years. Tom banned my account 3 years ago, so now I'm using an alias. Gonna ban this account too? What does my "outsider" status have to do with anything? Is it simply impossible for you guys to consider the ecosystem here instead of your own personal stakes? I guess not.

Comment: Again, you prove my point. The mods here consider some people "outsiders" and some people "insiders". Insiders have a game called "excluding" outside opinions. They do it to rack up points so they can demonstrate value to their supervisors and clients. That about sums it up.

Comment: And the mods here are NOT elected by the community. The election is only conducted by insiders and disregards the USERS who have left in disgust. They are the"community", not the insiders who run the elections.

Comment: "Personal stakes"? You have no idea how much work we've put into this, just because we feel responsible for the well-being of the community. I get nothing for that; I don't even do Wp jobs anymore for more than 3 years. By "outsider" I mean that your aren't even eligible to cast a vote in a moderator election, and you haven't done anything for the community, not even a single review. Btw, accounts don't get "banned" here. The maximum is is a one year suspension, and that happens only in _very_ rare circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I sympathise with your frustration because I share it. However, a flush of rep and a reboot will not fix anything.

Here is why. Whatever is wrong with WPSE is fundamentally wrong. It is a deep down in the core of the community issue. Thus a reboot will only result in the same issues growing right back up.

To change WPSE we must identify what is wrong - I've made a start [here](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/is-our-question-guidance-documentation-broken) - or fork and compete. Which is what we do with open source coding projects. If we fork we must build from the ground up without knowing if we have just baked back in the same problems. That leaves only trace the wetware bugs and fix them one by one. Maybe the community will recover of maybe we take it out back and give it the last mercy. Unless we try, change and growth cannot happen.

Perhaps the right thing to do is identify specific points of pain and thrash out solutions to them? I don't know because if I had all the answers I'd be implementing them.

Do you want to open a bug report on our community?